# .NET Framework SDK vs .NET Framework

Tags: .net

At this URL https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx is said that

the .NET Framework is already installed into Windows 10, 8, etc.

But I don't understand if this installation contains compiler tools, etc.

In Java I can install only the JRE and only the SDK that contains the JRE.

Is this the same into Windows with .NET Framework?

Is there a .NET Framework and a .NET Framework SDK?

If I don't install Visual Studio but I have Windows 10 can I program for .NET?

Comment: The *runtime* is installed, not the SDK.

Comment: This is not totally correct. Look at my comment given to @Filburt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can program for .NET just with the tools that come with the .NET Framework installed on Windows 10, 8, 7, etc. - just fire up Notepad and start hacking away.

csc.exe is your C# compiler (vbc.exe if Visual Basic is more to your liking).

There are dedicated SDKs to develop .NET programs for various API/technologies like SharePoint, Exchange, etc.

Comment: In fact I installed a clean version of Windows 10 and I found into C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ csc.exe, ldasm.exe, etc. So I presume that .NET installation doesn't contain only the runtime but also some SDK tools even if not complete as those provided with Windows SDK. Is this correct?

Comment: This is correct - the Windows SDK is an extension set of tools like those already mentioned and comes with Visual Studio. Since SDKs can be installed independently from Visual Studio this offers the opportunity to build assemblies even without Visual Studio: If a client hands you a Solution and the SDK it references, you can build it on a vanilla Windows machine. (SDK needs to be installed)